# Sync SharePoint O365 document Library with On-premise SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

I have our company SharePoint 2013 on-premise intranet application.
Also, I have access to our parent company O365 site.

There is document library in O365 site. I would like to create/clone that library in my on-premise site and I would like to sync these libraries. so the files in both libraries are up to date.

Is this is possible?